# Difference between #!/bin/sh and #:/bin/sh

Tags: bash

Someone send me a script today starting with #: and after googling I didn't found any answer.

Even if the script works I wonder what does that mean.

Comment: It may be a typo when he or she was refering to `#!`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wow! That's brings backs lots of memories!

Back in the 1980s and early 1990s, there were two basic shells, Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) and C shell (`/bin/csh`).

Bourne shell had very few user friendly things. There were no aliases or command substitutions. Therefore, most people liked using C Shell as their default shell.

However, Csh was a terrible scripting language. (See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Therefore, you used C shell as your shell, but wrote your scripts in Bourne shell which had a much better syntax.

However, there was a tiny little problem: Since your default shell is C Shell, typing a shell script name at the command line, and the C Shell would pick it up and try to execute it.

To get around this, you put `:` as the first line in your program. This was a Bourne shell comment, but was an invalid C Shell command. Thus the script would fail to run if you forgot to put `sh` in front of it.

Later on, systems would know if the first line was `:`, it should be a Bourne shell script. And, even later, you could put `#:` so it would be a comment and not a command. Some people put the name of the shell, `/bin/sh` next to it to help remind people were suppose to run this as a Bourne shell script.

C shell started dying out after Kornshell started becoming popular. It was about this time when the shebang (`#!`) came out, but that was only for AT&T and not the Berkeley derived systems. BSD systems didn't get the shebang until the late 1980s. And, Sun people used C Shell as their default shell until Solaris came out.

I hadn't seen a program begin with `#: /bin/sh` in ages.

BTW, it is common to start your scripts this way:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

This way, you use the version of Perl that's in your path and don't have to worry what directory it is in. For example, if you begin your script with:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
```

And, Perl is actually in `/usr/bin`, your script won't run. The `env` program is always in `/usr/bin` and is guaranteed to work. Of course, if you want to use a specific version of Perl and not the one that is in the path, you'd go with the first method.

Comment: There are [some odd systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) that have `env` elsewhere, I believe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this relevant complete answer !!

Comment: @Dennis: I certainly didn't know there were systems with /bin/env instead of /usr/bin/env. That makes things trickier. However, the two systems pointed out were SCO's OpenServer and the Cray UNICO (or something like that). I haven't seen a Cray in years, and I don't think SCO will be around much longer. Okay, /usr/bin/env isn't universal, but it's pretty damn close. Heck, even the universal <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant">fine-structure constant</a>, Alpha, may not be universal.

Comment: In order to avoid creating miniature black holes that destroy us all, use `[text](http://example.com)` to form links in comments instead of `<a href>...` ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment only...

```
#:/bin/sh
```

a shebang is #!. Everything else starting with a # is a comment.

example:

run a script starting with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

and it'll be run by perl. Now, replace the '!' by ':' and you'll run it with the defaut interpreter, which is your shell.

Comment: Completely correct. Just a small note. A space is preferred after the `#!` for historical reasons.

Comment: @Diego: I believe those historical reasons relate to such obscure and obsolescent systems that these days, no-one uses the space any more.

Comment: You can also do "#! /usr/bin/env perl". That way, the script will work as long as "perl" is in your $PATH environment variable. I've had systems with Perl in /bin, /usr/bin/, or /usr/local/bin. It is a pain when you test a script on one system and have it fail on another because you put "#! /bin/perl" in your script, but it's in "/usr/local/bin/perl" on the other machine.

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, I use them, maybe out of nostalgia :) @David: This is nice.